# How to create VirtualScroll effect on Blazor server

Tags: c#, blazor, infinite-scroll, blazor-server-side

**Hi there, thank you for taking time reading my problem.**

I have a blazor component called `Product.blazor`

```
<div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="@Image" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Random Text</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    Random rand = new Random();
    public string Image { get; set; } = "https://localhost:44322/unnamed.gif";
}
```

also, I have another blazer component `ListOfProducts.razor`, where I display a list of 1000 product.

```
@page "/products"

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <Product></Product>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

I looked at this [Github Repo](https://samprof.github.io/BlazorVirtualScrolling/), but I couldn't make it run.
So, can you please help me complete this task?.

It'd be better to not use any `Nuget` packages.

Answer (score 1):

In the following link you can find an example working

https://github.com/amuste/DnetVirtualScrolling

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no, it seems not to be working on dynamic height ```div```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question does not specify that dynamic height is necessary. you should edit the question and provide all the necessary details